# Subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead of an error callback

Tags: callback, rxjs, deprecated, tslint, subscribe

When I run the linter it says:

```
subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead of an error callback
```

Code from [this angular app](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular-example-app):

```js
    this.userService.updateUser(data).pipe(
       tap(() => {bla bla bla})
    ).subscribe(
       this.handleUpdateResponse.bind(this),
       this.handleError.bind(this)
    );
```

Don't know exactly what should I use and how...

Thanks!

Comment: * so try using `.subscribe({ next: this.handleUpdateResponse.bind(this), error: this.handleError.bind(this) })`

Comment: I don't manage to make it work using my apiRest

Comment: A detailed answer could be found here https://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2019/8/27/What-is-the-new-syntax-for-subscribing-to-Observables

Answer (score 480, accepted):

`subscribe` isn't deprecated, only the variant you're using is deprecated. In the future, `subscribe` will only take one argument: either the `next` handler (a function) or an observer object.

So in your case you should use:

```
.subscribe({
   next: this.handleUpdateResponse.bind(this),
   error: this.handleError.bind(this)
});
```

See these GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/4202
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4159

Comment: idk... hovering in vs code still shows deprecated with that syntax (rxjs 6.5.3)

Comment: Hey @YannicHamann [this comment](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4159#issuecomment-466630791) explains why. It's not deprecated, they just deprecated one of the overloads and now it looks like everything is deprecated. It's a tooling issue mostly.

Comment: I think this answer is not anymore valid since all subscribe methods are deprecated now in rxjs 6.5.4

Comment: It there a migration script that will automatically update all our `subscribe()` methods? We have hundreds of them in our project, I can't imagine having to do this manually!

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran how are we suposed subscribe nowadays?

Comment: We actually went to a normal method without rxjs for the same.

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran *Not* all methods are deprecated now. It's just that certain tools misinterpret the source and think all are deprecated. (see: [Code on github](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5e95503828798326947fc1dc1b98f69e9e04058c/src/internal/Observable.ts#L71))

Comment: Hmm, weird. The deprecated warning does not disappear after fix.

Comment: I'm using the preferred syntax in all my components and still getting the deprecation message.

Answer (score 171):

Maybe interesting to note that the `observer` Object can also (still) contain the `complete()` method and other, additional properties. Example:

```
.subscribe({
    complete: () => { ... }, // completeHandler
    error: () => { ... },    // errorHandler 
    next: () => { ... },     // nextHandler
    someOtherProperty: 42
});
```

This way it is much easier to omit certain methods. With the old signature it was necessary to supply `undefined` and stick to the order of arguments. Now it's much clearer when for instance only supplying a next and complete handler.

Comment: How to access `real this`, if using this form?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with `real this`. It's always possible to use a variable, something like `let scopedThis = this` or you can you `bind()` for instance.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! When passing an `observer` object into `subscribe()` there is no need to explicitly type `undefined` as a missing argument when you don't want to specify `next()` or `error()` callbacks.

Answer (score 55):

For me, it was just the typescript version my VSCode was pointing to.

[image: VSCode status bar]

[image: TypeScript version selector]

[image: Select local TypeScript version]

Got help from this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4159#issuecomment-791659997).

> I believe this is a typescript issue. Something in the newest versions of typescript is causing this warning to display in vs code. I was able to get it to go away by click the version of typescript in the bottom right corner of vs code and then choosing the select typescript version option. I set it to the node_modules version we have installed in our angular project which in our case happens to be 4.0.7. This caused the warnings to go away.

Answer (score 33):

Find the details at official website
https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

Notice the `{}` braces in second subscribe code below.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

// recommended 
of([1,2,3]).subscribe((v) => console.info(v));
// also recommended
of([1,2,3]).subscribe({
    next: (v) => console.log(v),
    error: (e) => console.error(e),
    complete: () => console.info('complete') 
})
```

Answer (score 23):

You can get this error if you have an object typed as `Observable<T> | Observable<T2>` - as opposed to `Observable<T|T2>`.

For example:

```
    const obs = (new Date().getTime() % 2 == 0) ? of(123) : of('ABC');
```

The compiler does *not* make `obs` of type `Observable<number | string>`.

It may surprise you that the following will give you the error `Use an observer instead of a complete callback` and `Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.`

```
obs.subscribe(value => {

});
```

It's because it can be one of two different types and the compiler isn't smart enough to reconcile them.

You need to change your code to return `Observable<number | string>` instead of `Observable<number> | Observable<string>`. The subtleties of this will vary depending upon what you're doing.

Comment: This worked for me, **deleteNoteType( NoteTypeId: number ): Observable<HttpResponse<undefined> | HttpErrorResponse> { ... }**

Answer (score 21):

The new Way of using RxJS is quit simple:

previous versions:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
console.log("queryParams, queryParams)

}, error => {
})
```

New Version:

```
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(
  {
    next: (queryParams) => {
      console.log('queryParams', queryParams);
    },

    error: (err: any) => { },
    complete: () => { }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

I migrated my `Angular` project from `TSLint` to `ESLint` and it is now not showing the warning anymore!

I followed these steps. (End of each step I also recommend to commit the changes)

1. Add eslint:
   `ng add @angular-eslint/schematics`
2. Convert tslint to eslint:
   `ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint`
3. Remove `tslint` and `codelyzer`: `npm uninstall -S tslint codelyzer`
4. If you like to auto fix many of the Lint issues
   `ng lint --fix` (It will also list the not fixed issues)
5. In VSCode uninstall the `TSLint` plugin, install `ESLint` plugin and Reload the VSCode.
6. Make sure it updated the package and package-lock files. Also the node_modules in your project.
7. If you have the `tsconfig.json` files under sub directory - you need to add/update the `projects-root-directory/.vscode/settings.json` with the sub directory where the `tsconfig` files are!

   ```json
   {
     "eslint.workingDirectories": [
       "sub-directory-where-tsconfig-files-are"
     ]
   }
   ```

- Information at VS Code official Page: [Migrate from TSLint to ESLint](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/tslint-eslint-migration) (Thanks for pointing this out in the comment!)
- Angular migrate from TSLint to ESLint [Reference](https://trungk18.com/experience/migrate-angular-eslint/)

Comment: More details here, about migration from TSLint to ESNint, in VS Code official page: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/tslint-eslint-migration

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the warning because I was passing this to subscribe:

```
myObs.subscribe(() => someFunction());
```

Since it returns a single value, it was incompatible with `subscribe`'s function signature.

Switching to this made the warning go away (returns null/void);

```
myObs.subscribe(() => {
  someFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace tslint with eslint.

As TSLint is being deprecated it does not support the `@deprecated` syntax of RXJS. ESLint is the correct linter to use, to do subscribe linting correctly.

Comment: I don't think this solution is good, because ignoring a problem doesn't solve it.

Comment: In this case it's not a matter of ignoring the problem because seems to be only a TSLint bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66605060/2445651 ... but more important to know is that TSLint has been deprecated in favour of ESLint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66933996/2445651

Comment: It's not ignoring, it removes a false error.

Answer (score 1):

The new syntax of subscribe :

```js
 this.fetch().subscribe({
        next: (account: Account) => {
            console.log(account);
            console.log("Your code ...");
        },

        error: (e) => {
            console.error(e);
        },

        complete() {
          console.log("is completed");
        },
});
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the complete callback? Is it somewhat similar to promise finally ?