# subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead of a complete callback for test

Tags: angular, rxjs

I read following question [Subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead of an error callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472124/subscribe-is-deprecated-use-an-observer-instead-of-an-error-callback)

but i have another case

expect(closedSubscription.subscribe).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);

lint wrote next error:

```
subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead of a complete callback
```

How to fix this case?

Comment: I think there is not enough code here to help. Is `closedSubscription.subscribe` a spy?

Comment: See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472124/subscribe-is-deprecated-use-an-observer-instead-of-an-error-callback

Comment: More specifically, scroll down to the answer by magikMaker in the other thread. You can provide an object to give different callbacks, including one for 'complete'.