# 'subscribe' is deprecated. Use an observer instead of a complete callback

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-formly

Hi am having the following error with SonarQube
'subscribe' is deprecated. Use an observer instead of a complete callback.
Am using formly in angular 9.
Thank you for your help and time

```
              onInit: (field: UiFormFieldConfig) => {
                const CostsControl = FormUtil.getControl(field.form, ContactDetailsFieldKey.Costs);
                CostsControl?.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((Cost: string) => {
                  if (Cost) {
                    const costsToSet = !Codes ? null : Cost;
                    field?.formControl?.setValue(costsToSet);
                  }
                });
              },
            },
```

Please find updated code and yet sonarQube is popping this message
'subscribe' is deprecated. Use an observer instead of a complete callback

```
  hooks: {
              onInit: (field: UiFormFieldConfig) => {
                const CostsControl = FormUtil.getControl(field.form, ContactDetailsFieldKey.Costs);
                CostsControl ?.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe({
                  next: (Cost: string) => {
                    if (Cost) {
                      const costsToSet = !Codes ? null : Cost;
                      field?.formControl?.setValue(costsToSet);
                    }
                  },
                });
              },
            },
```

Comment: maybe you need to add "next": func with depricaded method? 
.subscribe({
   next: this.handleUpdateResponse.bind(this),
   error: this.handleError.bind(this)
});

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472124/subscribe-is-deprecated-use-an-observer-instead-of-an-error-callback

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead of an error callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472124/subscribe-is-deprecated-use-an-observer-instead-of-an-error-callback)

Comment: @PhilippMeissner not really sounds a bit confusing for me. Any guide will be heartly appreciated :)

Comment: @snoopy Does it sound confusing, or are the provided examples simply not working? If so, what exactly did you try? (Add the code + errors to your question).

Comment: I am using Angular 10, typescript 4.0.7, [this answer used ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66691738/5146390)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer @Philipp Meissner mentioned, you should simple do:

```
CostsControl?.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(
    next: (Cost: string) => {
        if (Cost) {
            const costsToSet = !Codes ? null : Cost;
            field?.formControl?.setValue(costsToSet);
        }
    },
    error: () => { // log error }
});
```

Comment: i did same , but sonarQube sitll complain 'subscribe' is deprecated. Use an observer instead of a complete callback. Is there another approach to this issue

Comment: Edit your initial question and add the code you've tried. If you did everything right the error has to go away.

Comment: again for your help . Please find my updated question with the new code shown below the my initial code .  Thank you for your time and response