# Angular 15: error "subscribe is deprecated" still present after changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, eslint, tslint

I use Webstorm editor and I work with Angular 15.
I get the following message for subscribe function : "Deprecated symbol used"
I found this post and on the rxjs site that the method has changed:
[Angular 11: subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604826/angular-11-subscribe-is-deprecated-use-an-observer-instead)

So i have updated my code :

```
test() {

// Recommended
    this.backendServices.getAllBox().subscribe(
        (response) => {
            console.log(response);
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
            console.log('complete');
        }
    );
}
```

But the message is still present :
[image]

Then I found on google that this error can be produced by tslint and it is recommended to convert tslint by eslint.
It's what I do by following this tuto :https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+change+tslint+to+eslint&newwindow=1&sca_esv=582242121&rlz=1C1CHBF_frFR843FR843&sxsrf=AM9HkKkuhEYk7LWdKCbD7df9l3CiseljJA%3A1699960850354&ei=ElhTZeybFeK6kdUPtr2K-AM&oq=how+to+change+tslin&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiE2hvdyB0byBjaGFuZ2UgdHNsaW4qAggAMgYQABgWGB4yCBAAGBYYHhgKMgYQABgWGB4yBhAAGBYYHkj7eVAAWJtocAF4AZABAJgBuwGgAccUqgEEMC4yMLgBA8gBAPgBAcICBBAjGCfCAgcQIxiKBRgnwgILEAAYgAQYsQMYgwHCAhEQLhiDARjHARixAxjRAxiABMICCxAuGIAEGMcBGK8BwgIOEC4YgAQYsQMYgwEY1ALCAgsQLhiDARixAxiKBcICCxAAGIoFGLEDGIMBwgIFEAAYgATCAhEQLhiABBixAxiDARjHARjRA8ICBRAuGIAEwgIIEC4YgAQYsQPCAggQABiABBixA8ICCBAuGIAEGNQCwgIIEAAYigUYsQPCAhcQLhiABBixAxiXBRjcBBjeBBjgBNgBAcICCRAAGA0YExiABMICBxAAGBMYgATCAggQABgWGB4YE-IDBBgAIEGIBgG6BgYIARABGBQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:8749a8e7,vid:fsr6CFqqsLc,st:0

This is commands :
[image]

Angular.json et package.json have been updated as following :
[image]
[image]

But the error is still present.

What is missing ?

EDIT: my getAllBox method:

```
 getAllBox() {
    return this.http.get<ApiResponse>(this.apiUrl + '/api/site/all');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just the calling signature of subscribe which is deprecated.

instead of:

```
obs$.subscribe(() => {}, () => {}, () => {})
```

you should use the current recommended way:

```
obs$.subscribe({next:() => {},error: () => {], complete: () => {}})
```

From Observable.ts:

```
  subscribe(observer?: Partial<Observer<T>>): Subscription;
  subscribe(next: (value: T) => void): Subscription;
  /** @deprecated Instead of passing separate callback arguments, use an observer argument. Signatures taking separate callback arguments will be removed in v8. Details: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments */
  subscribe(next?: ((value: T) => void) | null, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null, complete?: (() => void) | null): Subscription;
```

personal view:

For the most cases i just use the subscribe signature only with the next callback, for errors i use the `catchError` operator for complete i use `finalize`

Comment: I understand but why the error is still present ? I use now the current recommended way...(see my first image) I have edit my post by adding the code of the method that is called. May be it comes for it.

Comment: You don't use the recommended way in your answer. That is to pass an object with next, error, complete *properties* (which contain the callback functions). You're passing the callback functions as parameters directly.