# How to use observable instead of complete callback / Angular @11

Tags: javascript, angular2-observables, angular11

I wander how I can resolve this.

```
this.signupForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
    (value) => console.log(value);
  )
```

I obtain a message:

> Subscription is deprecated. Use an observer instead of complete
> callback

Comment: A similar question was asked, please refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472124/subscribe-is-deprecated-use-an-observer-instead-of-an-error-callback#:~:text=subscribe%20isn%27t%20deprecated,handleError.bind(this)%0A%7D)%3B

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
this.signupForm.valueChanges.subscribe({
    next: (value) => console.log(value)
  })
```

In this way, it works fine.