# Subscriptions to HTTP GET Requests No Longer Return Properly Typed Value in RxJS 7.5

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, rxjs7

So, here is my simple GET request:

```
async getInspectionForm(): Promise<Observable<InspectionSummaryFormField[]>> {
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('InspectionType', this.inspection.InspectionType);
params = params.append('includeInactive', 'false');

const httpComponents = await this.httpService.composeRequest('/InspectionFormCriteria', params);

return this.http.get<InspectionSummaryFormField[]>(httpComponents.fullUrl, httpComponents.httpOptions); }
```

Here is where I consume the result:

```
this.inspectionFormCritera.subscribe(formCriteria => {

  this.inspectionStorageService.inspectionFormCriteria = formCriteria;

  for(const f of formCriteria) {
    this.inspectionSummaryForm.addControl(f.FormInputName, new FormControl('', Validators.required));

    this.saveValuesOnFormChange(f.FormInputName);

    if(f.EndpointName) {
      this.dropdownFieldIterator++;
    }

    if(f.RadioSelections) {
      this.radioSelections.push(f.RadioSelections.split('-', 5)); // Because radio button selections are defined in the database like so: option1-option2-option3.
      this.inspectionStorageService.formSelections.radioSelections = this.radioSelections;
    }
  }

  this.prepareDropdownFields(formCriteria);
}, error => {
  this.newInspectionsService.inspectionDownloadTimeoutError(error);
});
```

However, the above use of the subscription method is deprecated in my current version of RxJS 7.5 ... So I use the preferred syntax of moving the error handler into the `error:  () => {}` notifier function inside the subscribe call. However, my formCriteria object no longer unwraps from the observable with type InspectionSummaryFormField[], but instead with the 'any' type.

Is this just a beta issue or am I missing something important here?

Comment: Well, for anyone who happens to come across this and is curious - from what I can tell, RxJS just wants you to have to explicitly type your return on both ends (the http request and the callback function parameter). You must assign the type of the original request (or the 'any' type) or it will tell you that you're missing properties of the object. I suppose it's a good enforcement for readability.

Comment: You're using a deprecated notation for `subscribe()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472124/subscribe-is-deprecated-use-an-observer-instead-of-an-error-callback/55472361#55472361