# RxJS subcribe is deprecated

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have trouble with subcribe method. In vscode it says that subcribe is deprecated but I have no clue how to change it properly.

```
  public getAccount(): void{
    this.accountService.getAccounts().subscribe(
      (response: Account[]) => {
        this.accounts = response;
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: there was a discussion going on in github issue regarding the same. So it is probably because of vscode update and ESlint something. Visit this link
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43053

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead of an error callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472124/subscribe-is-deprecated-use-an-observer-instead-of-an-error-callback)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass an observer object instead of multiple callbacks. All signatures that used multiple arguments were deprecated.

```
this.accountService.getAccounts().subscribe({
  next: (response: Account[]) => {
    this.accounts = response;
  },
  error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    alert(error.message);
  },
  complete: () => {
    // do something when the observable completes
  }
});
```

If you don't need an error and complete callbacks, you can still use it like this: `.subscribe((value) => console.log(value))`.

You can read about why the signature you're using was deprecated [here](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments#what-signature-is-affected).