# other blocks of code gets executed after subscribe in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this function to upload file after the file is uploaded it returned uploaded path then
i pass it to tiny url  `this.tinyUrl.shorten(data.url).subscribe(sUrl => { shortUrl=sUrl;});`
but the issue is `sUrl` is returned with certain delay and further code gets executed i want till `sUrl` is not returned the next code should not be executed.

```
handleUpload(file) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const contentType = file[0].type;
      const bucket = new S3(
        {
          .....
        }
      );
      .....
      bucket.upload(params, (err, data)=> {
        if (err) {
       
          return false;
        } else {
          if (data.url) {
            this.tinyUrl.shorten(data.url).subscribe(sUrl => {
              shortUrl=sUrl;
            });
          }
          resolve(this.FileUploadImage);
        }
      });
      setTimeout(() => {                        
       
      }, 4000);
    });
 

  }
```

Any solution Thanks

Comment: Try to resolve in subscribe when url is ready.

Comment: @Taras Can you post it in Answer with example

Comment: does it work for you correct? or you want more details provided?

Comment: @Taras Still not working please post your code so that i can try

Comment: Not sure if it is answer, but try this.tinyUrl.shorten(data.url).subscribe(sUrl => {shortUrl=sUrl; resolve(this.FileUploadImage);});

Answer (score 2):

If you subscribe to something, its asynchronous. So everything outside of the subscribe will be executed, like you experienced. If you want something to happen after the subscription returned a value, it needs to be done inside the subscription, for example like Taras did:

```
this.tinyUrl.shorten(data.url).subscribe(sUrl => {
  shortUrl=sUrl; 
  this.FileUploadImage();
});
this.nextMethod();
```

`this.FileUploadImage()` will be executed when the subscription received a return. `this.nextMethod();` will be instantly executed, after the subscription starts.

Keep in mind, that subscribing like this is deprecated ([Subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead of an error callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472124/subscribe-is-deprecated-use-an-observer-instead-of-an-error-callback)).