# Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554) in Subscribe Error handler

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs7, angular14upgrade

we have just recently upgraded Rxjs Latest(8.0.0-alpha.5) version.And this error started appearing.

```
this.ReportController.ExportTableExcelBackground(model).subscribe(
            (x) => {
              this.appController.BlockApplication(false);
              if (x.IsSuccess) {
                const msgInfo = "The report will be downloaded when finished.";
                this.alertController.RegisterAlertMessage(
                  [msgInfo],
                  AlertMessageType.SUCCESS,
                  true
                );
              } else {
                this.appController.OpenErrorServerPopup(x.Message);
              }
            },
            (error: any) => {
              this.appController.BlockApplication(false);
              this.appController.OpenErrorServerPopup(error);
            }
          );
```

When hover on error it says **Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2**
Any idea what is changed in RXJS latest version and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What line in this code show the error?

Is it the `subscribe()` call? `Observable.subscribe()` declaration has changed since RxJS 7 and the way you're using it has been deprecated and in RxJS 8 removed. If you want to handle two notification types you'll need to use an observer object:

```
source$.subscribe({
  next: () => {},
  error: e => {},
});
```

Just FYI [Subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead of an error callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472124/subscribe-is-deprecated-use-an-observer-instead-of-an-error-callback/55472361#55472361).

Comment: It's showing on error handling method  which is this part 
(error: any) => {
              this.appController.BlockApplication(false);
              this.appController.OpenErrorServerPopup(error);
            }
in my case

Comment: The you need to do what I described in my answer

Comment: Thanks i will change my code as per you answer